# iOS - CFUnderline text in attributes of CFMutableAttributedString

Tags: objective-c, ios8, nsattributedstring, core-text, underline

Some propositions have emerged about this problem but it cannot be fixed. I try to underline (or even better to strikethrough) a text created for a PDF file. I use CF text like this:

```
+ (void)drawAllText:(NSString *)textToDraw inFrame:(CGRect)frameRect forTag:(NSInteger)tag {

CFMutableAttributedStringRef currentText = CFAttributedStringCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
CFAttributedStringReplaceString (currentText, CFRangeMake(0, 0), (CFStringRef) textToDraw);

NSDictionary *fontAttributes = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
fontAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      @"Verdana", (NSString *)kCTFontFamilyNameAttribute,
                      kCTUnderlineStyleSingle, (id)kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName,
                      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:8.0], (NSString *)kCTFontSizeAttribute,
                      nil];
CTFontDescriptorRef descriptor = CTFontDescriptorCreateWithAttributes((CFDictionaryRef)fontAttributes);
```

Verdana and size 8.0 work fine but impossible to underline the text. I cannot neither change color (like [UIColor redColor].CGColor, (NSString *)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName).

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName` nor `kCTForegroundColorAttributeName` are **font** attributes. They don't belong in the dictionary you pass to `CTFontDescriptorCreateWithAttributes()`. The valid font attributes are listed in the `CTFontDescriptor` docs, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/carbon/reference/CTFontDescriptorRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005107-CH4-SW11).

`kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName` and `kCTForegroundColorAttributeName` are attributes that can be applied in an attributed string. You could pass them to `CFAttributedStringSetAttribute()` or in the dictionary argument to `CFAttributedStringSetAttributes()`, etc.

Finally, if you're going to put `kCTUnderlineStyleSingle` as a value in a dictionary, it needs to be wrapped in an `NSNumber` object. You can do that using a "boxing" expression such as `@(kCTUnderlineStyleSingle)`.